# Incrementing column headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please help me to solve the below issue.

From the initial data frame given below, I want to create a new data frame based on a column condition like this:

`if mean > median, add 1 to A & -1 to B,  elif mean < median, add -1 to A & 1 to B,  else add 0 to both A and B.`

**Initial Data Frame:**

```
    A/B     A/C     A/D     B/C     B/D     C/D
0   0.75    0.61    1.07    0.82    1.43    1.75
1   1.21    10.88   2.17    9       1.8     0.2
2   0.95    0.85    1.97    0.9     2.08    2.32
3   0.47    0.47    0.91    1       1.94    1.94
```

---

[image: Mean and Median]

Then final output data frame should consist of total score of all elements like below:

[image: Output DataFrame]

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `add 1 to A & -1 to B`? Where are columns `A` and `B`?

Comment: Hi Mayank, A and B are in column header in A/B format. so based on column condition, they both should be assigned a point respectively. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#count mean and median
df1 = df.agg(['mean','median']).round(2)
#difference in sample data so set 0.85
df1.loc['mean', 'A/B'] = 0.85
```

First transpose DataFrame and split `index` to `MultiIndex` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = df1.T
df1.index = df1.index.str.split('/', expand=True)
```

Then compare `mean` with `median` and set new 2 columns in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df1['mean'].gt(df1['median']).to_numpy()[:, None]
m2 = df1['mean'].eq(df1['median']).to_numpy()[:, None]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1, m2], [[1,-1], [0,0]], [-1, 1]),
                   index=df1.index,
                   columns=['a','b'])
print (df1)
      a  b
A B   0  0
  C   1 -1
  D   1 -1
B C   1 -1
  D  -1  1
C D  -1  1
```

Last use `sum` per both index and join together:

```
df2 = (pd.concat([df1.a.droplevel(1), df1.b.droplevel(0)])
         .sum(level=0)
         .rename_axis('Element')
         .reset_index(name='Total Score'))
print (df2)
  Element  Total Score
0       A            2
1       B            0
2       C           -3
3       D            1
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, it seems your code is perfect as you got the output. However, I am getting "KeyError: "None of [Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]". I checked for any inconsistencies, but all are working except this. Kindly help me to resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: @Arya - So working well for you `df1[['a','b']] = np.select([m1, m2], [[1,-1], [0,0]], [-1, 1])` ? If not, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I am usinf pandas version - '1.0.5'. thanks.

Comment: @Arya - So working `df1[['a','b']] = np.select([m1, m2], [[1,-1], [0,0]], [-1, 1])` ?

Comment: @Arya - Can you try edited answer? `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1, m2], [[1,-1], [0,0]], [-1, 1]),
                   index=df1.index,
                   columns=['a','b'])`

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much once again.